# Weird EOFException on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My Android application uses `URLConnection` to connect to a webservice. It's in the market over a year now and works quite well. However, problems with Galaxy Nexus users came up recently:

When getting the input stream (not even reading yet!) from the `URLConnection` like:

```
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()), 8192);
```

A `EOFException` is thrown at `getInputStream()`.

First I thought this may be an ICS problem, so I installed an early build on my Nexus S, but there I couldn't reproduce the problem. Then I got access to a Galaxy Nexus, which crashes in the same way as the bug reports I've received, which makes me believe that it's probably not a case of a single phone acting weird.

The stack trace of the crash can be seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-xbmcremote/issues/detail?id=581) and the whole code on [GitHub](https://github.com/freezy/android-xbmcremote/blob/master/src/org/xbmc/httpapi/Connection.java#L278). It's really weird, the app has some 100k+ installations on Android Market and the problem only seem to occur on the Galaxy Nexus.

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It also happens on my Vibrant running ICS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen the same issue on my Xperia Arc S (Note! Non-ICS) during development of my app. I'm almost certain that we see the same symptom of two different problems, though.

In my case I was reading the entire stream as a UTF8 `String` but the server side implementation was expecting me to read the first byte as a numeric `byte` and the rest of it as UTF8 `String`.

I'm not sure on the details for why I *really* got an `EOFException`, but reading the stream, paying attention to the types in the custom protocol in it, solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! There are some more hints at the bug tracker on Google Code. Will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Actually, the server I was connecting to didn't send the "Connection: close" header. Adding it explicitly to the client header solved the problem.

Comment: Ahh! What a bastard (the server, that is). I have to check if this might also be the root cause for my symptoms. Great work on tracking this bug, and thanks for sharing!

Comment: Indeed. It's fixed now on server side too, so problems concerning that one should disappear soon. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm seeing this same error on ICS, I "fixed" it by disabling keepAlive:

```
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```