# Android HttpURLConnection throwing EOFException

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, eofexception

Here's the question in simplest way.

I create a HTTPS connection to my server through proxy using HttpUrlConnection Object.

My proxy closes the connection but my code still tries to reuse the same connection. And so I get EOFException.

How do I handle such cases?

Comment: EOF = end of file. It has nothing to read.

Comment: Because you are using the same connection, which still has the previous data in it. You have to clear everything.

Comment: Post some example code. You only state that "you do the same" in the comments to answers. We would know that if you showed it.

Comment: The final status of this question is unclear. Please clarify.

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend disabling the http.keepalive system property. The performance section of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) indicates that socket connections will be reused when possible. It sounds like it is trying to reuse the connection, but the proxy has already closed it. On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487780/weird-eofexception-on-galaxy-nexus), Darrell also indicates that changing the system property solved his problem.

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

Comment: that will close connection everytime and slows down network connection. :( I don't want to do that.

Comment: I agree that reusing the connections would be better. Have you made sure that the InputStream you get from the connection is closed after being used?

Comment: If I close the input stream I will be releasing all the resources held by the stream including the underlying socket. So connection cannot be reused in that case.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put disconnected the connection http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()

Comment: I'm not clear on what you would like clarified, but since this answer Square has released their [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp) library. OkHttp handles many of the idiosyncrasies of HTTP/S on Android for you (and supports SPDY!).

Comment: Found that Samsung Galaxy S III isn't working with this fix. Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, as well as Nexus 10 and Nexus 4, all work though. I've had issues in the past with Galaxy S III acting differently, so not quite sure how to handle this...

Comment: It doesn't work on Android Emulator, API 16 with a slow connection. I think, a problem is in server's settings, because no exception happens with a fast connection.

Comment: I met this problem on Android Emulator. I just turn off the proxy (in Android Studio settings), the problem goes away. While this may not be a fundamental solution.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out they've fixed this issue in Android on Jan 8th [1]. The fix basically marks the old connection as recycled and internally retries the request.

To fix this for now, I would suggest retrying requests if an EOFException is encountered with a retry limit to prevent stackoverlows.

1. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/19aa40c81c48ff98ccc7272f2a3c41479b806376

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with normal HTTP connections as well. The first request went OK, the second failed with an EOFException.

Eventuelly I fixed it by removing...

```
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

...from the HttpUrlConnection.

I could be that the webserver I'm calling can't handle chuncked data well. Don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reuse the connection then release it.

```
finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to pick data from server then you convert the inputs trim to string then you can parse for further use.`

```
  public static InputStream getUrlData(final String url)
        throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
    final HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
    return res.getEntity().getContent();
    }
```

Comment: HttpClient is buggy and very slow (and effectively deprecated.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `httpClient` "has more bugs" and is deprecated, but this problem with JellyBean is a showstopper. I am using Ksoap2 so I tried all the suggested answers that I could.

- `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");`
- `httpTransportSE.getServiceConnection().setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");`
- `httpTransportSE.getServiceConnection().disconnect();`

Nothing worked - my solution was to rollback the version of Ksoap2 I'm using from 3.1.1 to 2.6.5. Using 2.6.5 the problem is substantially reduced. Still testing but maybe even solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found that retrying the connection fixes the issue as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302767/2520390

Make sure you close off the connection before your recursive call.

Also, I added the following to the connection to close the connection, though I'm not sure if it helps:

```
if (retries > 0) {
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be attempting to reuse the same HttpURLConnection instance. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in the very bottom line of the "Class Overview" say

> Each instance of HttpURLConnection may be used for one
>   request/response pair.

Keep-Alive connections work at a different level, see the disconnect docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()

> Unlike other Java implementations, this will not necessarily close
>   socket connections that can be reused. You can disable all connection
>   reuse by setting the http.keepAlive system property to false before
>   issuing any HTTP requests.

So you should always use a fresh HttpURLConnection and let the socket pool handle re-use.

There were apparently bugs with keep-alive connections pre-Froyo (2.2) so it is recommended to disable keep-alive on those old devices.

In my case the EOFException was caused by my server not sending a full response, see the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27845172/2335025

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be attempting to reuse the same HttpURLConnection instance. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in the very bottom line of the "Class Overview" say

> Each instance of HttpURLConnection may be used for one
>   request/response pair.

Keep-Alive connections work at a different level, see the disconnect docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()

> Unlike other Java implementations, this will not necessarily close
>   socket connections that can be reused. You can disable all connection
>   reuse by setting the http.keepAlive system property to false before
>   issuing any HTTP requests.

So you should always use a fresh HttpURLConnection and let the socket pool handle re-use. There are perhaps issues if it tries to reuse a socket that has been closed by the server, which the answers to this question deal with: [Android HttpUrlConnection EOFException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19258518/2335025)

There were apparently bugs with keep-alive connections pre-Froyo (2.2) so it is recommended to disable keep-alive on those old devices.

In my case the EOFException was caused by my server not sending a full response, see the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27845939/2335025

Comment: Please remove this duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null
                        && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
                    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                }
```

Comment: Could you add some text to explain your solution?

Comment: i am not sure but there is a bug in some version of android(newer ones) on recycled url connection, which can be fixed by this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:`

Httppost method:

```
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("put_url");
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

    String file = resourceXml();


    StringEntity se = null;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(file);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
    se.setContentType("application/xml");
    request.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String _response = convertStreamToString(is);

    Log.i(TAG, "Response:" + _response);
    // Check if server response is valid code
    int res_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.i(TAG, "status_code" + res_code);
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`

Comment: httpClient has far more bugs than httpurlconnection. It is recommended to use HttpURLConnection.

Comment: use method convertStreamToString();

Answer (score -1):

to convert stream to string:`

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),
            8192);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();

}`
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing in there.

Comment: The first time i'm connecting everything's fine. When I do it the second time, it says EOFException on `conn.connect()`. And this happens only if I hve set a proxy at the device level.