# EOFException at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203) when using HttpDelete in HttpsURLConnection

Tags: android, web-services, rest, httpclient, inputstream

I face a error message that is

```
java.io.EOFException
at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
com.example.rest.MainActivity.excutePost(MainActivity.java:354)
at com.example.rest.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:86)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

and my code is

```
URL url = new URL(url);
con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
con.setRequestProperty("userID", "user20@yahoo.com");
con.setRequestProperty("password", "xyz123");
con.setRequestMethod(HttpDelete.METHOD_NAME);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
con.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
String convertInputStreamToString = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
```

I have tried these links

- [Android HttpUrlConnection EOFException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258518/android-httpurlconnection-eofexception)
- [Android HttpsUrlConnection eofexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411213/android-httpsurlconnection-eofexception)
- [Android HttpURLConnection throwing EOFException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319194/android-httpurlconnection-throwing-eofexception)

Comment: Did you resolved this issue?