# "unexpected end of stream" thrown during NetHttpRequest.execute() when uploading file

Tags: android, network-programming

This has been asked in a couple questions but I've yet to see a real answer. I've got Android code that executes a NetHttpRequest to POST an image to a server, but it often fails quickly like so:

```
unexpected end of stream java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream
    at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.close(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:58)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1009)
    at com.test.MyActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:870)
    at com.test.MyActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I don't get it... why fail like this? Given the backtrace it makes me believe that it must have something to do with the HTTP library prematurely closing the connection, but I can't determine why. Most of the related questions have exactly the same problem (e.g. [Uploading jpeg to Google Drive from Android app "unexpected end of stream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469588/uploading-jpeg-to-google-drive-from-android-app-unexpected-end-of-stream), ) except in every case the question goes unanswered or the asker finds some strange workaround that seems to solve it for them (although they are likely just getting lucky).

My upload code isn't anything special either, just an AsyncTask that creates an HttpRequest and executes it. It works perfectly fine most of the time, but other times it fails inexplicably. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.

After more debugging I was able to eliminate a lot of variables and convinced myself this bug had to exist in the core HTTP library. Some googling found some people referencing bugs in Android's implementation of HTTP keep alive (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9291, [Weird EOFException on Galaxy Nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487780/weird-eofexception-on-galaxy-nexus), etc.).

So I added this code to my activity:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

And that fixed my problem. Annoying workaround, but it works.

Comment: still gettting errror.